# Insert query not working with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know if wrote something wrong in the query, or if it's a logic error. The problem is on the second to last line.

```
<?php
include "connectdb.php";
$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["userId"]);

$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE userId='userId'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($q1);
if($num==1){
    //user exists, update visits and unique values
    $visits = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
        $visits = $row["visits"] + 1;
        echo $row["visits"] + 1;
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE visitors SET visits='$visits',unique='no' WHERE userId='$userId'");
    die();
}
//if there is no current visitor
mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitors(userId,visits,unique) VALUES('$userId','1','yes')");
?>
```

EDIT: userId and visits are both set to INT in the database.

Comment: I really don't know what happened here.

Comment: does `mysql_num_rows($q1)` actually return `1`? You appear to be inserting this user into `visitors` each time this code run since your `INSERT` statement follows your `if` block unconditionally.

Comment: You do realize the this will increase your echo'ed result by `2` instead of `1` - `$visits = $row["visits"] + 1; echo $row["visits"] + 1;` - Just do `echo $visits;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i think first error in in variable name using  in $ql and second is $num==1 if in visitors table multiple record of thats user then this condition will be wrong ($num==1) so i think replace it with  this ($num>0) 

<?php
include "connectdb.php";
$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["userId"]);

$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE userId='$userId' ");
$num = mysql_num_rows($q1);
if($num>0)
{
    //user exists, update visits and unique values
    $visits = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
    {
        $visits = $row["visits"] + 1;
        echo $row["visits"] + 1;
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE visitors SET visits='$visits',unique='no' WHERE userId='$userId'");
    die();
}
//if there is no current visitor
mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitors(`userId`,`visits`,`unique`) VALUES ('$userId','1','yes') ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **1.**

Change:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE userId='userId'");
```

to:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE userId=$userId");
```

### **2.**

Delete the single quotes around `$userId` in your SQL queries (since it's an INT). It should be like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE visitors SET visits='$visits',`unique`='no' WHERE userId=$userId");
```

and:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitors(userId,visits,`unique`) VALUES($userId,'1','yes')");
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that, I would have never found it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add error handling to your sql queries, but the problem (after the correction indicated by @DanielLisik) is the use of a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html): `unique`.

Change your query to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitors(userId,visits,`unique`) VALUES('$userId','1','yes')");
```

You should also consider changing to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. What key do you use for the ` mark?

Comment: @AdamS. Ummmmm, I'm on a Spanish keyboard but if you're still interested: `AltGr` - `}`. Twice :-)